# How to debug karma tests with ndb (running in karma-electron)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, google-chrome-devtools, karma-runner

I've got Karma using Electron to run tests. I'd like to get devtools open so I can step through the unit test code.

I tried using `ndb`,

```sh
ndb ./node_modules/.bin/karma ...args...
```

but after the devtools window opens, nothing runs, there are no source files, nothing is paused.

My Karma config looks like this:

```js
module.exports = function(config) {

    config.set({

        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'stacktrace'],
        reporters: ['spec'],
        port: 9876,  // karma web server port
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        // singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity,

        basePath: CWD,

        browsers: ['Electron'],
        files: [
            '.karma-test-build/**/*.js',
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            '.karma-test-build/**/*.js': ['electron'],
        },
        client: {
            // otherwise "require is not defined"
            useIframe: false,
            loadScriptsViaRequire: true,
        },

    })

}
```

Also available [here](https://github.com/trusktr/builder-js-package/blob/master/config/karma.config.js).

Any idea how I can use `ndb` to debug the tests running inside Karma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find if there's a way to test Karma with Electron using ndb, but what I did find is that making a custom launcher that extends karma-electron's launcher allows us to pass the `--show` option, as shown in this karma-electron issue on GitHub: https://github.com/twolfson/karma-electron/issues/18, which then allows us to hit the "Debug" button in the window that opens, then we can open the devtools inside of the Electron window to debug tests. After the devtools are open, we need to refresh the page to force tests to run again (that way it will stop on break points or debugger lines).